# strange jags.parallel error / avoiding lazy evaluation in function call

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation, jags, r2jags, jags.parallel

I have a function call (to `jags.parallel`) that works when given a numerical argument like `n.iter = 100` but fails when the argument uses a variable value, `n.iter = n.iter`.  This looks like it might be a bug in `jags.parallel`

A minimal reproducible example of the error:

```
    library(R2jags)
    model.file <- system.file(package="R2jags", "model", "schools.txt")
    J <- 8.0
    y <- c(28.4,7.9,-2.8,6.8,-0.6,0.6,18.0,12.2)
    sd <- c(14.9,10.2,16.3,11.0,9.4,11.4,10.4,17.6)    
    jags.data <- list("y","sd","J")
    jags.params <- c("mu","sigma","theta")
    jags.inits <- function(){
      list("mu"=rnorm(1),"sigma"=runif(1),"theta"=rnorm(J))
    }
```

Then this works:

```
    jagsfit.p <- jags.parallel(data=jags.data, inits=jags.inits, jags.params, 
                               n.iter=5000, model.file=model.file)
```

But this does not:

```
     n.iter=5000
    jagsfit.p <- jags.parallel(data=jags.data, inits=jags.inits, jags.params,
                               n.iter=n.iter, model.file=model.file)
```

Giving the error:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)) : 
  3 nodes produced errors; first error: object 'n.iter' not found
```

I gather this has something to do with not exporting the variable `n.iter` to the cluster, but it is not clear what parallel engine jags.parallel is using.  Is there any way to trick R to evaluate `n.iter` before passing it to the function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`do.call()` is a great go-to friend in situations like this because (from `?do.call`):

> If 'quote' is 'FALSE', the default, then the arguments are
>    evaluated (in the calling environment, not in 'envir').

I confirmed that the following works, producing results that match your `jagsfit.p` through all digits displayed by the result object's print method:

```
jagsfit.p2 <- do.call(jags.parallel, 
                      list(data=jags.data, inits=jags.inits, jags.params,
                           n.iter=n.iter, model.file=model.file))
```

Comment: What would one do if the data were actually stored in a list? I.e. if you had all the data as `mydata=list(y=c(28.4,7.9,-2.8,6.8,-0.6,0.6,18.0,12.2), sd=c(14.9,10.2,16.3,11.0,9.4,11.4,10.4,17.6), J=8.0)`? I've run jags(data=mydata, ETC.) before, but with the do.call method here it doesn't work because the names are not found in the environment it's searching in.

Comment: @user29020 -- Sorry, I don't use jags enough for your question to be making quick sense to me, and no one else will see it here on a 2.5-year old question. I'd recommend you ask it as a question in its own right, together with a reproducible example, on SO. (You can of course link to this question and answer in your own question.) Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I prefer to keep old SO/SE questions in order to reduce duplication. Anyway, it turns out that my question was asked. I just hadn't found it yet. Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23790452/using-jags-parallel-from-within-a-function-r-language-error-in-getname-envir?rq=1

Comment: @user29020 Great! Glad to hear that you found that, and thanks for reporting back here. As you say, it's good to keep these related questions well interlinked.