# jags.parallel - Error in get(name, envir = envir) : invalid first argument

Tags: r, winbugs, jags, r2jags, jags.parallel

When using `jags.parallel`, I get the following error:

```
> out <- jags.parallel(win.data, inits, params, "Poisson.OD.t.test.txt",
+ nc, ni, nb, nt);
Error in get(name, envir = envir) : invalid first argument
```

The same call using `jags` function runs OK. I have only found [one thread on this topic](http://sourceforge.net/p/mcmc-jags/discussion/610037/thread/8f9dd526/), but there is only one speculative suggestion that does not apply nor work here.

Reproducible code, taken from [Introduction to WinBUGS for ecologists, see chapter 14.1](http://www.mbr-pwrc.usgs.gov/software/kerybook/R_WB_code.txt) (slightly modified):

```
set.seed(123)

### 14.1.2. Data generation
n.site <- 10
x <- gl(n = 2, k = n.site, labels = c("grassland", "arable"))
eps <- rnorm(2*n.site, mean = 0, sd = 0.5)# Normal random effect
lambda.OD <- exp(0.69 +(0.92*(as.numeric(x)-1) + eps) )
lambda.Poisson <- exp(0.69 +(0.92*(as.numeric(x)-1)) ) # For comparison

C.OD <- rpois(n = 2*n.site, lambda = lambda.OD)
C.Poisson <- rpois(n = 2*n.site, lambda = lambda.Poisson)

### 14.1.4. Analysis using WinBUGS
# Define model
sink("Poisson.OD.t.test.txt")
cat("
model {
# Priors
 alpha ~ dnorm(0,0.001)
 beta ~ dnorm(0,0.001)
 sigma ~ dunif(0, 10)   
 tau <- 1 / (sigma * sigma)
 maybe_overdisp <- mean(exp_eps[])

# Likelihood
 for (i in 1:n) {
    C.OD[i] ~ dpois(lambda[i]) 
    log(lambda[i]) <- alpha + beta *x[i] #+ eps[i]
    eps[i] ~ dnorm(0, tau)
    exp_eps[i] <- exp(eps[i])
 }
}
",fill=TRUE)
sink()


# Bundle data
win.data <- list(C.OD = C.OD, x = as.numeric(x)-1, n = length(x))

# Inits function
inits <- function(){ list(alpha=rlnorm(1), beta=rlnorm(1), sigma = rlnorm(1))}

# Parameters to estimate
params <- c("lambda","alpha", "beta", "sigma", "maybe_overdisp")

# MCMC settings
nc <- 3     # Number of chains
ni <- 3000     # Number of draws from posterior per chain
nb <- 1000     # Number of draws to discard as burn-in
nt <- 5     # Thinning rate

require(R2jags)

# THIS WORKS FINE
out <- R2jags::jags(win.data, inits, params, "Poisson.OD.t.test.txt",
    nc, ni, nb, nt);

# THIS PRODUCES ERROR
out <- jags.parallel(win.data, inits, params, "Poisson.OD.t.test.txt",
    nc, ni, nb, nt);

# THIS ALSO PRODUCES ERROR
out <- do.call(jags.parallel, list(win.data, inits, params, "Poisson.OD.t.test.txt",
    nc, ni, nb, nt));
```

Comment: The error occurs because the first argument to `get` must be a character string naming a function. Use `traceback` to see which function calls `get` and produces the error, then `debug` that function to investigate the objects in the function body. Or you can use `options(error=recover)` (and turn it off via `options(error=NULL)`).

Comment: Thanks @Joshua! So this actually leads to debugging the jags package, not my code, right? If we conclude it is a bug, then maybe I the best strategy is to report to jags developers?

Comment: Not sure. I'm not familiar with these packages and didn't run the code, so it could still be one of your functions (e.g. maybe `inits` should be `"inits"` in the `jags.parallel` call?)... but that should be clear to you once you run `traceback`.

Comment: Possibly not unrelated: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21367922/684229

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jags/R had practically two problems with this line:

```
out <- jags.parallel(win.data, inits, params, "Poisson.OD.t.test.txt",
    nc, ni, nb, nt);
```

Both are related to evaluation of function parameters - he is probably not able to resolve parameters which refer to other R variables:

1) The `win.data` was encoded as variable names as usually for WinBUGS/Jags:

```
win.data <- list(C.OD = C.OD, x = as.numeric(x)-1, n = length(x))`
```

but `jags.parallel` issues the error "Error in get(name, envir = envir) : invalid first argument". He wants the data in this format:

```
windata <- list("C.OD", "x", "n")
```

Why? Don't ask me... I discovered this when reading the example of `?jags`.

2) The arguments `nc, ni, nb, nt` in function call are a problem! If I put constants, it is OK, but references to variables are unacceptable for him. Don't ask me why. Remedy found at [strange jags.parallel error / avoiding lazy evaluation in function call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16723036/684229).

The complete fix looks like:

```
out <- do.call(jags.parallel, list(names(win.data), inits, params, "Poisson.OD.t.test.txt",
    nc, ni, nb, nt));
```

Comment: Thanks! I can add that the model MUST be a filename. A textConnection(modelString) doesn't work. I used sink(), cat() and file.remove() to handle the file.

Comment: @Jonas, exactly - I do it like this all the time.

Comment: @TMS, a quick question, does jags.parallel actually parallelize? I mean, does it need other packages like ``snow`` to do the parallelization, or does it parallelize different chains by itself and we don't need to take care of that part? Thanks!

Comment: @qkhhly I don't actually remember, but I *think* it actualy parallelizes. But I gave up completely on using R2jags and this function, since there have been many bugs and strange problems like this one. I am using runjags package now and I am satisfied. With the `run.jags` function you can just specify `method = "rjparallel"` and the chains will run on separate cores. And the best thing is that it *actually works* :-)

Comment: @TMS & @qkhhly, I think (at least `R2jags` version 0.5-7) uses the R package `parallel` to initialize clusters etc. It does have some nice wrappers for exporting objects to the cluster.

Comment: @TMS, the why this format for `windata` works might be how the package figures out what to export to the cluster... btw.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes this error occurs when you use a vectorized function inside parlapply. I've solved the problem by adding "do.call" and "mapply" functions to cluster.export

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).