# Jags error when using jags.parallel(): "all connections are in use"

Tags: r, jags, r2jags

I am using the `R2Jags` package and I want to use the `jags.parallel` function to speed up computations. I use the following code:

```
jags.data <- list("y", "N")
    n.chains = 3
    n.burnin=5000
    n.thin=1
    n.iter=10000
    mod_ss = do.call(jags.parallel, list(jags.data, jags.params, model.file=model.loc, n.chains, n.burnin, n.thin, n.iter))
```

The error that I get is `Error in file(con, "w") : all connections are in use`.

Does anyone know what could cause this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not reproducible. Please make it.

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct way of using this function?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Yes, I took it from the poster here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808575/jags-parallel-error-in-getname-envir-envir-invalid-first-argument